# Realization (in the sense of homotopy coherent nerve) of $\partial\Delta^n$

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

I need some help understanding the working of the homotopy coherent nerve (as described in Lurie's HTT).

Let $i < j$, then $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak{C}\Delta^n}(i, j) \simeq (\Delta^1)^{(j-i-1)}$, and for any $i < j$ with $(i,j) \neq (0,n)$ we have $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak{C}\Delta^n}(i, j) =\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak{C}\partial\Delta^n}(i, j)$.

Lurie states that $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak{C}\partial\Delta^n}(0, n) = \partial(\Delta^1)^{n-1}$. Why is this so?

Update: I'm now semi-convinced (having computed it by hand on some examples), however I'm having problems proving it. Any help?

Comment: What are those symbols. I cannot even look them up.

Comment: @Student One way to find that out is to download a copy of Lurie's book (and read it).

Comment: I cannot afford that book right now. @RooibosTee

Comment: What does $\mathfrak{C}\Delta^n(i, j)$ stand for? What about $(\Delta^1)^{(j-i-1)}$ and $\partial\Delta^n(k, n)$?

Comment: @Student You may download a *free* copy at http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie.

Comment: (*free* as in "free beer")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$. The simplicial category $\mathfrak{C} [\partial \Delta^n]$ has as objects the set $\{0,\ldots,n\}$, and the simplicial set $Hom_{\mathfrak{C}[ \partial \Delta^n]}(i,j)$, for $0 \leq i < j \leq n$ and $(i,j) \neq (0,n)$, is $N(P_{i,j})$, the nerve of the partially ordered set of subsets $I \subseteq \{ i,\ldots,j \}$ with $i,j \in I$. The  simplicial set of morphisms $Hom_{\mathfrak{C} [\partial \Delta^n]}(0,n)$ is the union over all chains of objects $0 = x_0 < \ldots < x_l = n$ of the image of the map $N(P_{x_0,x_1}) \times \ldots \times N(P_{x_{l-1},x_l}) \rightarrow N(P_{0,n}) = Hom_{\mathfrak{C} [\Delta^n]}(0,n)$. You'll find that a $k$-simplex of $Hom_{\mathfrak{C} [\Delta^n]}(0,n)$ is a chain $I_0 \subseteq I_1 \subseteq \ldots \subseteq I_k \subseteq \{ 0,\ldots,n \}$ with $0,n \in I_0$, and this $k$-simplex is in $Hom_{\mathfrak{C} [\partial \Delta^n]}(0,n)$ if and only if either $I_0 \neq \{ 0,n \}$ or $I_k \neq \{ 0,1,\ldots,n \}$. If you regard $Hom_{\mathfrak{C} [\Delta^n]}(0,n)$ as a box $(\Delta^1)^{n-1}$, then $Hom_{\mathfrak{C}[\partial \Delta^n]}(0,n)$ corresponds precisely to the "boundary" of that box.

Comment: I can't find a definition for the "boundary of a box" in Lurie's book. Is it standard? Could somebody please give a reference?

Comment: The "boundary" of the box $(\Delta^1)^n$ is basically what you get if you remove the "diagonal" $\Delta^1 \rightarrow (\Delta^1)^n$.

Comment: Whereas the boundary of a simplex $\Delta^n$ is basically what you get if you remove the maximal sub-simplex $\mathrm{id} \colon \Delta^n \rightarrow \Delta^n$.

Comment: I found a good reference for the definition of the "boundary of a box": http://www.math.uwo.ca/~jardine/papers/sPre/lecture012.pdf, by Jardine. Also take a look at http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cube+category.